# Apache host with multiple alias/domains rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an apache vhost with a server and multiple aliases. The server being the production/live domain and the aliases being the dev and staging servers. For example:

```
ServerName foo.bar
ServerAlias dev.superfoo.bar
ServerAlias stage.superfoo.bar
```

Is there a rewrite rule that would preserve the domain, whatever it may be, and just redirect people from domain/en-us/anything to domain/en/anything?

I believe that ^/en-us/(.*)$ foo.bar/en/1$ would do the trick for one domain. Is there a way to preserve the domain instead of writing the rule for every alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the correct domain is retained on each one, you may use the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable in the redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en-us/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The `[R=301]` flag issues a permanent 301 redirect, but in testing you may want to use 302 since browsers might aggressively cache the redirect making it hard to debug.

Above I used the leading `/` as in `^/en-us`. That will be necessary if you use this rule at the VirtualHost level. However, if you use it inside a .htaccess file in your document root, you must not include the `/`, as in:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en-us/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The rules around that are noted [in the "what is matched" section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what-is-matched) of the `RewriteRule` manual.

Comment: Thanks for the concise well written answer. And thanks for the link. I feel silly for not finding that on my own. I wasn't able to properly write what I wanted to search.